# Find partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $\ u,v,x,y$ are related by the following equations:

$\ xyu -yv^2 +x^2 = 0$ and $\ 4u^2 -2v^2 -x^3y = 0$, find

1)$\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

2)$\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$

My question is: Do I only have to find the partail derivatives of each function? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: What are those expressions equal to? Should there be an equal sign between those expressions?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post, they're equal to 0

Comment: It's the same procedure as with your previous question. Did you try to follow the idea?

Comment: Easiest is to solve for $u$ first, then find the derivative. Implicit differentiation also works.

Comment: So, can I solve this by solving the equations for u,v,x,y and then derivate?

Comment: Yeah. That should be alright. Lots of computation though.

Comment: You can also try implicit differentiation, if you can't/don't want to solve for a given variable